# Having trouble Installing visual studio 2013 its Installer window is way off

Tags: visual-studio-2013

The first image is what I get when I Run Its executable. The window itself still responds and when you close this.

[image]

I get the second Image under this where i can vaguely tell that its response is yes or no.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Install visual stdio from command prompt this link is useful http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/quickest-way-install-windows-software-command-prompt/